# Why can't I import "models.User"?

Tags: python, python-import

This works.

```
from django.contrib.auth import load_backend, login
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
```

However, this, does not.

```
from django.contrib.auth import load_backend, login, models.User
```

Why doesn't the latter work? Isn't `models` a module within the `django.contrib.auth` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Semantically, that would make sense but due to python's grammar the following is a syntax error. (I agree with python's choice here.)

```
from django.contrib.auth import models.User
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to import `User` before importing the `models` itself. It's like you're doing

```
from  import django.contrib.auth.models.User
```

The above code doesn't work in any scenario. Hope Guido won't see this awkward answer.